# How to Compose Query in BigQuery with Destination Table?

Tags: python-2.7, google-bigquery

I am trying to Query on a BQ table and load that queried data into destination table with use of legacy_sql

**Code:**

```
bigquery_client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(config.ZF_FILE)
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
job_config.use_legacy_sql = True

# Allow for query results larger than the maximum response size
job_config.allow_large_results = True

# When large results are allowed, a destination table must be set.
dest_dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset('datasetId')
dest_table_ref = dest_dataset_ref.table('datasetId:mydestTable')
job_config.destination = dest_table_ref

query =""" SELECT abc FROM [{0}] LIMIT 10 """.format(mySourcetable_name)

# run the Query here now
query_job = bigquery_client.query(query, job_config=job_config)
```

**Error:**

```
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 POST : Invalid dataset ID "datasetId:mydestTable". Dataset IDs must be alphanumeric (plus underscores, dashes, and colons) and must be at most 1024 characters long.
```

The job_config.destination gives :

```
print job_config.destination

TableReference(u'projectName', 'projectName:dataset', 'projectName:dataset.mydest_table')
```

The datasetId is correct from my side still the error?

May I know how to get the proper destination table ?

Comment: I'm confused. Don't you want `dest_dataset_ref.table('mydestTable')`?

Comment: @ElliottBrossard , I have mentioned the same , job_config.destination requires TableReference which I mentioned above. So why the error Invalid datasetID?

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? It seems like you need to remove `datasetId:` from the table name.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard yeah it worked just by naming its dataset_name instead of dataset_Id as the dataset_id contains full path like projectID:datasetname

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpfull to someone  in future

It worked by just naming only the Names instead of full Id of dataset and table as below

```
dest_dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset('dataset_name')
dest_table_ref = dest_dataset_ref.table('mydestTable_name')
```

Comment: That is correct! I've thoroughly tested your code with latest api version and the confussion in my case (and probably also @Elliot's too) is that the code and Error you've posted do not match. It complained with: Invalid dataset ID "datasetId:mydestTable" , but you were setting: bigquery_client.dataset('datasetId')